# inquire two information from the for loop python

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, nested-loops

For example I have this code :

```
path_real = r'C:/Users/SLR CSV'
all_files_real = glob.glob(os.path.join(path , "2*.csv.zip"))

list_real = []

for filename in all_files_real:
    df_real = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, sep=';')
    list_real.append(df_real)
```

So, my list_real is the collection of dataframe.
And, If  I want to do a `for` loop for each list_real, I will do

```
for lst in list_real :
    lst=datareal
    ***some code to calculation***
    a=[]
    
    *another for loop
         b=x/zzz
         a.append(b)
```

Is that possible, in the outer for loop, beside getting lst as each of dataframe, I can iterate for each number of list_real (*I mean len(list_real)).
So, at the end I hope I can get 2d matrix that its column represent `a` calculation from each dataframe.

So, I can add :

```
for i in range (row):
        matrix[i][col]=a[i]
```

My problem is, that col value I do not know how to iterate, lst refer to each df not number of df. collection . Is there a way I can iterate the df it self and also, number of df so I can put this number on my matrix(i)(*desired variable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you described, you can use the enumerate function to loop through the list_real and get the index of each element (dataframe) as well as the element itself. This way, you can use the index to keep track of the column number in the matrix.

Here is how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```py
# Create an empty matrix with the desired number of rows
    matrix = [[0 for j in range(len(list_real))] for i in range(len(a))]

# Loop through the list_real and get the index and element (dataframe)
for col, lst in enumerate(list_real):
    lst = datareal
    # Some code to calculation
    a = []

    # Another for loop
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        b = lst[i] / zzz
        a.append(b)

    # Fill the matrix with the values in a
    for i in range(len(a)):
        matrix[i][col] = a[i]
```

This will create a matrix with the desired number of rows and columns, and fill it with the values calculated from each dataframe in list_real. The matrix will have as many columns as there are elements in list_real, and the values in each column will correspond to the calculation from the corresponding dataframe.

Comment: thanks, but that matrix will not be succesfully created unless we define 'a' first right ?
meanwhile, a will be defined after?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The matrix will not be successfully created unless a is defined first. In the code you provided, a is defined within the inner loop, so it will be overwritten on each iteration of the inner loop.

Comment: Yes, that I understand. So how do I prepare a "place" for that matrix if we do not know yet the shape.

Comment: If you don't know the shape of the matrix in advance, one option is to create an empty list and append the rows to it as you calculate them. You can then use the numpy library to create a matrix from the list once you have all the rows.